# using thread/block-safe collection to coordinate multiple asynchronous operations? (NSMutableArray or NSMutableSet)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, thread-safety, objective-c-blocks

I'm writing some code to sync objects between a client and a server. It involves a bunch of HTTP calls (which I'm not making myself but using the Parse library) with blocks for callbacks. I want to wait until a set of these calls are done, then take a further action. Along the way I need to store the result of each call somewhere.

The easiest way I can think of is to keep a counter and a collection -- something like an NSMutableArray or NSMutableSet. Each time an HTTP operation finishes I store its result in the collection and increment the counter. Then I check the counter, and if it equals the total number of operations I proceed to the next step. (I'm proposing a counter rather than the size of the collection since I may not need to store an object for each HTTP call.)

But I'm guessing I get into thread safety issues: what happens when two calls return simultaneously and both try and add to the collection and/or increment the counter?

What's the solution here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what GCD is designed to handle. What you want are called Dispatch Groups. See the [GCD Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) and look at the section "Using Dispatch Groups." With a dispatch group, you submit various blocks as part of a group, and a "notify" block that is called when the group completes, no matter how they're scheduled.